# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'addLayout'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have this UIWidget class in `PyQT5 and Python3` as follow.

```
class UIWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UIWidget, self).__init__(parent)        
        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()        

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Face")

        self.display = PlayStreaming()
        # Create first tab
        self.createGridLayout()
        self.tab1.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.display, stretch=1)
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)

    def createGridLayout(self):
        hlay1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()   
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("")
        self.horizontalGroupBox.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox{ background-color: red; border: none;}")          
        self.ScaleUpButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton('ScaleUp')
        self.ScaleUpButton.clicked.connect(self.display.scaleupSignal)
        hlay1.addWidget(self.ScaleUpButton) 
        self.ScaleDownButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton('ScaleDown')
        self.ScaleDownButton.clicked.connect(self.display.scaledownSignal)
        hlay1.addWidget(self.ScaleDownButton) 
        self.resetButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton('Reset')
        hlay1.addWidget(self.resetButton)
        self.resetButton.clicked.connect(self.display.resetallarraysSignal)
        self.RecognizeButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton('Recognize')
        self.RecognizeButton.clicked.connect(self.display.send_signal)
        hlay1.addWidget(self.RecognizeButton)             
        self.layout.addLayout(hlay1)
        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Trying to allocate `Vertical layout to Horizontal layout`.

This line `self.layout.addLayout(hlay1)` has error as

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'addLayout'
```

How can I solve the error?

Comment: change `self.layout` to `self.another_name` since layout is a method of the widgets so you are overwriting it and that always brings problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access `self.layout` **before** the `self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)` line in `__init__` has run. As such, `self.layout` is the [inherited method from the `QtWidgets.QWidget` base class](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.layout).

You probably want to use a different name altogether to not collide with the method on `QtWidgets.QWidget` in the first place.